# Can you spot why data sent to the server is returning `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to process a form submit, but the data that is sent to the server is coming back as undefined. I have tried to no avail debugging this file, but the console is returning `Status code 200` even though the backend comes back as `undefined`. I am hoping you can help debug this and point me in the right direction to resolving this issue. Thank you in advance. Here is the code below:

What I have done

1. Setup files on the front end with form to submit data
2. Set up the server file that is going to process the data.

`console.log(data)` returns 'undefined`

```jsx
// "/pages/frontendfile.js"

import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function EmailConvTool({ openModal, setOpenModal }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [beforeClick, setBeforeClick] = useState(
    "Complete the form field below",
  );
  const initialEmailForm = {
    email: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    brand_url: "/someurl",
    logo: "/images/file.png",
    email_body: "",
  };

  const [emailForm, setEmailForm] = useState(initialEmailForm);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  const [beforeButton, setBeforeButton] = useState("Click to Send");
  const [isEmailEmpty, setIsEmailEmpty] = useState(false);

  const url = "/api/serverfile.js";

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenModal(false);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setEmailForm((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsClicked(true);

    if (emailForm.email === "") {
      setIsEmailEmpty(true);
      setBeforeClick("Enter your email in the form below");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const { email, firstName, lastName, brand_url, logo, email_body } =
        emailForm;

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          brand_url,
          logo,
          email_body,
        }),
      });

      console.log("Server Response:", response); // returns Status code (200)

      const data = await response.json(); // Parse the response as JSON
      console.log("Parsed data", data); // returns Status code (200)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setError(
        "An error occurred while sending the email. Please try again or contact us for support.",
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                disabled={isClicked}
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                value={emailForm.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              {isEmailEmpty && !emailForm.email && isClicked && (
                <p className="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">
                  Please enter your email address
                </p>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="space-y-2">
              <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="firstName"
                id="firstName"
                disabled={isClicked}
                placeholder="Enter your first name"
                value={emailForm.firstName}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              {isEmailEmpty && !emailForm.firstName && isClicked && (
                <p>Please enter your first name</p>
              )}
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="lastName"
                id="lastName"
                disabled={isClicked}
                placeholder="Enter your last name"
                value={emailForm.lastName}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              {isEmailEmpty && !emailForm.lastName && isClicked && (
                <p>Please enter your last name</p>
              )}
            </div>

            <div>
              <button id="send" type="submit">
                {error ? <p>{error}</p> : <p>{beforeButton}</p>}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
// "/api/serverfile.js"

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { data } = req.body;
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      console.log(data); // returns undefined
      res.status(200).json({ message: "success" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    }
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Next.js version are you using?

Comment: `"next": "^13.4.12"`